# Intuition/motivation behind integral basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm learning some of the basics of algebraic number theory. Everything right now seems concerned with finding and calculating with integral bases of number fields. I suppose one nice use of integral bases is to distinguish number fields via their discriminants. But is there some nice intuition or motivation as to why one would look to an integral basis as a good object to consider associated to a number field?

Comment: Isn't it nice to know exactly which elements of your field are algebraic integers?

Comment: If you have an integral basis, you can consider the action of multiplication by any algebraic integer $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$ on this basis, which by integrality is a matrix with integer entries. Now you can define the norm and trace of $\alpha$ to be the determinant and trace of this matrix, and be guaranteed that they are integers.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I guess I should've asked why the ring of integers is so great, but maybe I will learn that soon.